# Print [Ljava.lang.String; list from frida

Tags: java, android, hook, frida, reversing

how can i print list of strings ([Ljava.lang.String;) from java in frida? I tried different methods but nothing works for me:

- `Java.use('java.util.Arrays').toString(arr)`
- `Java.array("java.lang.String",arr);`
- `JSON.stringify(arr)`

Comment: `Java.use('java.lang.String').join(", ", arg);` should work on Android as well as on regular JRE.

Answer (score 2):

solution:

```
Java.use('org.json.JSONArray').$new(arg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to cast the array and don't forget to call the `toArray()` method.

```
somehook["getUrlList"].implementation = function () {
    console.log(`UrlModel.getUrlList is called`);
    let result = this["getUrlList"]();
    var stringArray = Java.cast(result, 
    Java.use('java.util.List')).toArray();
    for (var i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
        console.log('String[' + i + ']: ' + stringArray[i]);
    }
    return result;
};
```